# Tables are not created in entity framework 6.1 Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I am learning Entity Framework 6.1 in Visual Studio 2013. I found a tutorial on web and created a sample project in Code First approach. But when I ran that it did not created any tables in my database which it supposed to. My project consists of `Student` class and `Subject` class:

```
class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        this.Subjects = new List<Subject>();
    }
}
```

`Subject.cs` :

```
class Subject
{
    public int SubjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Student student { get; set; }
}
```

Database context

```
class StudentContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

Database initializer:

```
 public DbInitializer()
    {
        var db = new StudentContext();
        Student student = new Student() { Name = "Tom" };
        Subject mathSubj = new Subject() { Name = "maths" };
        Subject scienceSubj = new Subject() { Name = "science" };
        student.Subjects.Add(mathSubj);
        student.Subjects.Add(scienceSubj);

        db.Students.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

I am creating an instance of  `DbInitializer` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

Any suggestions are helpful...

Comment: What happens when you debug with a breakpoint inside the `DbInitializer` constrictor? Does it hit?

Comment: And no exceptions? Did you checked the connectionstring? May be its creating it in some other database?

Comment: @Mathew no exceptions. Also Student object is created and populated with data but no table is created..

Comment: Most probably its using a different default connectionstring in that case. check your app.config/web.config. Check the connection string of `yourContext.Database.Connection` property.